# Get Current Location (as specified in Region and Language) in C#

Tags: c#, localization

How can I get machine's current location as specified in Region and Language of the OS? I have already tried getting this from the `RegionInfo` class but it returns Location as specified in Format drop down of Region and Language.

Just to clarify what I mean, If you open Region And Language from Control Panel of your machine, I want to read Location as specified in Location tab. RegionInfo gives me value as specified in Format dropdown of Formats tab.

Comment: @Sai I think the OP means the geographical location.

Comment: I think he wants Location as in *Ukraine, United States, United Kingdom* like wise and nothing to do with the culture

Comment: That is correct. For example, I can have my culture as English (United States) and my location as India. You can change both of these independently  in Region and Language control panel.

Answer (score 18):

After lot of googling, finally i got the answer. Following two links help me get the current machine location-

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharpgeneral/thread/6dfaa142-c588-4cb0-b044-fa1e8138b299

http://www.siao2.com/2007/02/21/1733999.aspx

I made the following utility class if anybody is interested in final code-

```
public static class RegionAndLanguageHelper
{
    #region Constants

    private const int GEO_FRIENDLYNAME = 8;

    #endregion

    #region Private Enums

    private enum GeoClass : int
    {
        Nation = 16,
        Region = 14,
    };

    #endregion

    #region Win32 Declarations

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int GetUserGeoID(GeoClass geoClass);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetUserDefaultLCID();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetGeoInfo(int geoid, int geoType, StringBuilder lpGeoData, int cchData, int langid);

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns machine current location as specified in Region and Language settings.
    /// </summary>
    public static string GetMachineCurrentLocation()
    {
        int geoId = GetUserGeoID(GeoClass.Nation); ;
        int lcid = GetUserDefaultLCID();
        StringBuilder locationBuffer = new StringBuilder(100);
        GetGeoInfo(geoId, GEO_FRIENDLYNAME, locationBuffer, locationBuffer.Capacity, lcid);

        return locationBuffer.ToString().Trim();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: This is the ONLY working solution on multiple OS, like Win7 + Win8. I don't understand why is not rated at all ...

Comment: `using (var regKeyGeo = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\International\Geo"))
        {
              Response.Write("<br />Geo Nation " + regKeyGeo.GetValue("Nation").ToString());
        }`

Comment: @Kiquenet Using the registry is something I would definitely avoid. That's generally undocumented and unsupported, and you can be pretty sure that it will break at some point.

Comment: Too long and not as elegant as what @Zan has stated below.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using

`RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.DisplayName;`

Does this give you the required Location name as you intend

Comment: I have tried this but it gives me current Format and not the current location as specified in Region and Language dialog (Control Panel ->Region and Language)

Comment: Will not work. My location is Japan, but the above shows "United States".

Comment: ***Not same*** `Control Panel: Regional and language options->Standards and formats` than  `Control Panel: Regional and language options->Location`

Answer (score 1):

Base on "Control Panel > Region > Home Location", you can get RegionInfo. Try this -

```
var regKeyGeoId = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\International\Geo");
var geoID = (string)regKeyGeoId.GetValue("Nation");
var allRegions = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).Select(x => new RegionInfo(x.ToString()));
var regionInfo = allRegions.FirstOrDefault(r => r.GeoId == Int32.Parse(geoID));
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer - much shorter. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972349/1266732

Answer (score 0):

yes.. but easier:

```
CultureInfo info = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
```

Comment: That does not work. For example, my Location tab is set to Japan. However, the above code generated en-US.

Comment: ***Not same*** `Control Panel: Regional and language options->Standards and formats` than  `Control Panel: Regional and language options->Location`