# GetGeoInfo - get country names in different languages

Tags: c#, winapi, localization, globalization

I'm trying to get a list of countries in a handful of different languages. The issue I've got is that I also need to match these to the GeoId from Windows, which can be found in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/table-of-geographical-locations) list.

I've been using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8891177/9234580) as a starting point, and trying to edit this so when I provide the list of codes that I want to get in multiple languages, I can change the language I want, and get the name of the country I need. This uses the [GetGeoInfo Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getgeoinfoa) to get the country details from the GeoId provided.

The code I have now been trying to get working as a proof of concept is here:

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    private enum SYSGEOTYPE
    {
        GEO_NATION = 0x0001,
        GEO_LATITUDE = 0x0002,
        GEO_LONGITUDE = 0x0003,
        GEO_ISO2 = 0x0004,
        GEO_ISO3 = 0x0005,
        GEO_RFC1766 = 0x0006,
        GEO_LCID = 0x0007,
        GEO_FRIENDLYNAME = 0x0008,
        GEO_OFFICIALNAME = 0x0009,
        GEO_TIMEZONES = 0x000A,
        GEO_OFFICIALLANGUAGES = 0x000B,
        GEO_ISO_UN_NUMBER = 0x000C,
        GEO_PARENT = 0x000D,
        GEO_DIALINGCODE = 0x000E,
        GEO_CURRENCYCODE = 0x000F,
        GEO_CURRENCYSYMBOL = 0x0010,
        GEO_NAME = 0x0011,
        GEO_ID = 0x0012
    };

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetUserDefaultLCID();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetGeoInfo(int geoid, int geoType, StringBuilder lpGeoData, int cchData, int lcid);

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns machine current location as specified in Region and Language settings.
    /// </summary>
    public static string GetLocationName()
    {
        var geoId = 94;
        var lcid = 94;
        var locationBuffer = new StringBuilder(100);
        GetGeoInfo(geoId, (int)SYSGEOTYPE.GEO_FRIENDLYNAME, locationBuffer, locationBuffer.Capacity, lcid);

        return locationBuffer.ToString().Trim();
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetLocationName());
    }
}
```

From playing around with this, if I change the `geoId` then it changes the country I am looking at, and that is working fine. If I try to change the lcid to anything, I'm not able to get it away from English. I am running in English on my Windows machine. I have trialled this on a VM, and installed the German language pack and then switched to it in Windows, and doing this then means that `GetGeoInfo` returns the country name in German.

What I don't understand is what does the last argument in the `GetGeoInfo` do, and is there a way I can use this to switch the language I want to retrieve from, even if I have to download a lot of language packs onto my machine to do this.

If there are any other ways of getting the country names in multiple languages along with the GeoId I'd love to hear them. I have looked at the [Unicode Common Locale Data Repository](https://cldr.unicode.org/) but I'll need to get my head around where exactly I need to pull the countries from, and I'll also need to remove the requirements I currently have with the GeoId before I can move to this, so I am looking at trying to get the `GetGeoInfo` API working in the meantime.

Comment: _What I don't understand is what does the last argument in the GetGeoInfo do_ - see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getgeoinfow): `The application must set this parameter to 0 if GeoType has any value other than GEO_RFC1766 or GEO_LCID.` ... `If Location is specified as 0xF4 for United States, GeoType is specified as GEO_RFC1766, and LangId is specified as 0x04 for Chinese, the function retrieves "zh-US" on successful return.`

Comment: Thanks for that, I've read it about 4 more times and think I understand that now. I was reading the previous paragraph which states `The application can set this parameter to 0, with GEO_RFC1766 or GEO_LCID specified for GeoType` But that is talking about how it uses `GetUserDefaultLangID` for this. 

Does this mean I will need to install all language packs I want to Windows, and assign the language in Windows and then run it one at a time, or is there a way in the winapi where I can change the active language?

Comment: With the "old" Windows NLS API you had to install language packs to get localized country names. Now Windows ships ICU https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/international-components-for-unicode--icu- it's possible you can get more information from it (I've not checked).